# inserting values from textbox created dynamic with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have the following script in jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {

            if (counter > 10) {
                alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                return false;
            }

            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

            newTextBoxDiv.html('<label>Raspuns' + counter + ' : </label>' +
       '<input type="text" name="textbox'  + counter +
       '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >' );

            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


            counter++;
        });

        $("#removeButton").click(function () {
            if (counter == 1) {
                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                return false;
            }

            counter--;

            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

        });


    });
```

This generates dynamic text boxes on push of a button. My question is: how can i get the values from this dynamic texboxes using c#.in php I made a foreach but in c# it doesn't work. Can you point me to a direction.I'm using c# in an asp.net application.I've updated my answer to jquery but still didn't figure it out how to get the values from the textboxes.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on your ASP.NET page and inspecting the contents of the POSTed data? It should be pretty clear what you have to do from the data structure alone. It is not even necessary to read the documentation, even though this would also be a good idea.

Comment: any html control modification added into the page via javascript wont be recognized by the server-side. Instead of reading the controls from server-side you can just pass the values via a asp hiddenfield

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use the Json (for instance, use JQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Try without the [] in the field name. Correct me if I'm wrong, but apparently [] is something that php invented and that is not necessary.

For example, my favorite framework (django) does not support fields with names like foo[], that said it does support multiple fields with name "foo". That's standard and that should be the case on c#.

Note that to test it, you should inspect the full post variables from c#.

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting the page, just read the values of the dynamic textboxes and put them(delimited by any special character) into an asp hiddenfield  via javascript, then submit. Now read the value of the hiddenfield from the server-side, split; you got the values

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically created fields, you have to use JSON.

Serialize the page data to JSON.

Now post the data using jQuery.

In code behind, you can de-serialize the JSON back to strings. Please visit [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C)